# How to make Window.Current visible after it was closed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an application that opens new windows. If the original window is closed and then the user starts the app (e.g. from the start menu) - `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` fails in opening a new window (Why?). So I want to "revive" the original one. But though I use `Window.Current.Activate();` and `frame.Navigate(...);` - `Window.Current.Visible` is always `false` (and the window is not shown again).

So how can I "revive" a closed window? (Or use `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` from a closed window.)

Answer (score 2):

I think `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` tries to use the main view as the anchor view (ie, a window to place the new window relative to).

Once you close the main window `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` fails because it has no anchor view.

The workaround is to specify an `anchorViewId` of a view that is open (one of the new windows you opened prior to closing the main window), via an overload of [TryShowAsStandaloneAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewswitcher#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationViewSwitcher_TryShowAsStandaloneAsync_System_Int32_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ViewSizePreference_System_Int32_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ViewSizePreference_):

```
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
    viewIdToShow, // Id of a new view, or of your hidden main view
    ViewSizePreference.Default,
    anchorViewId, // Id of one of your visible windows
    ViewSizePreference.Default);
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39883395/1438809).