# How can a universal windows app have multiple independent windows (Like Microsoft's app “Photos”)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

I do know how to open additional windows using `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync`. However, if the original window is closed - `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` fails (Why?). [And I don't know how to "revive" it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690029/how-to-make-window-current-visible-after-it-was-closed) (-the original window).

But "Photos" seems to work fine just like a desktop application. How does it do that? (I'd like to emulate that.) One can open a window with an image, open another one, close the first, and still be able to open more windows.

Any way would be fine - some way to launch windows without the main window showing, or some way of reviving the main window after it's closed (in order for it to be the new window that has to be opened), or some other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [MultipleViews sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/17b1dbd0985d3241582381fb50608e0449cc2537/Samples/MultipleViews). This app does have the problem you're describing.

Each view that you create will have their own UI Thread, and therefore dispatcher.
The key to this app is that `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` is called from the dispatcher of the currently active window.

In the sample's `OnLaunched` event, the code looks for a reference to the currently open view, using the view id from the launch arguments. It then uses the dispatcher associated with that view to call UI code, using `Dispatcher.RunAsync`, on that view's UI thread. You should use that thread of the open window to call `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` to launch your new main view. You can then call `Window.Activate` using the new main view's dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Answering why `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` fails once you have closed the main window:

I think `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` tries to use the main view as the anchor view (ie, a window to place the new window relative to).

Once you close the main window `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` fails because it has no anchor view.

The workaround is to specify an `anchorViewId` of a view that is open (one of the new windows you opened prior to closing the main window), via an overload of [TryShowAsStandaloneAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewswitcher#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationViewSwitcher_TryShowAsStandaloneAsync_System_Int32_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ViewSizePreference_System_Int32_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ViewSizePreference_):

```
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
    viewIdToShow, // Id of a new view, or of your hidden main view
    ViewSizePreference.Default,
    anchorViewId, // Id of one of your visible windows
    ViewSizePreference.Default);
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39883395/1438809).

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if you're using `Dispatcher.RunAsync` to create the view, i.e:

```
async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
 int newViewId = 0;

await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
 {
 var frame = new Frame();
 frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), newViewId);
 Window.Current.Content = frame;

// In Windows 10 UWP we need to activate our view first.
 // Let's do it now so that we can use TryShow...() and SwitchAsync().
 Window.Current.Activate();

newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
 });

 bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
 }
```

for more info, please refer to : https://daxsnippets.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/windows-10-create-views/

Comment: As I've said, I do know how to open additional windows. The problem is only after the main window is closed.