# uwp app with multiple windows on Win10: how to bring a specific window to the front

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I tried Window.Activate(), but that does not appear to bring up the specific window, just the app itself.

I have multiple windows that the app is managing, and I want to be able to bring up a specific window on demand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a universal windows app have multiple independent windows (Like Microsoft's app “Photos”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692322/how-can-a-universal-windows-app-have-multiple-independent-windows-like-microsof)

Comment: Nope, read the question carefully... I know how to open new windows. I want to bring one of these windows to the front... Activate does not appear to do that, just bring the app as a whole to the front, not the specific window I want to bring up...

Comment: I've got a solution rather a work around. I'll try it and post an answer. Gimme 2 hours. I am out currently

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for overshooting the two hours with 2 days but as promised below is your solution. It might not be the ideal way of achieving such a functionality but in my opinion it's a solution that works perfectly. I've uploaded a solution as well to one drive.

---

### The Solution:

To actually handle multiple window switching without relaunching a new window rather in your words:

> bring up a specific window on demand.

What you need is a window logging service. What this service would do is, each time it opens up a new window, it logs it along with the type of window opened. I've kept a neat `enum` to manage the windows that open.

I'll talk more about the window logging service more than the UI part as the UI is just basic buttons calling the service.

### The Window Service:

1. Make a singleton instance of the `windowLauncherService`
2. Maintain a private dictionary of `WindowIDs` and `TypeOfWindow` launched.
3. On call of the `HandleWindowSwitch` method, check if the window has already been launched (check if it exists in the private Dictionary), if it does simply call await `ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(Convert.ToInt32(existingViewID));`. Where you get the existingViewID from the key of the dictionary.
4. If the window has not been launched before, then simply launch the window and then log it.

That's it. Below is my WindowServiceCode:

```
namespace MultipleWindowTracker.Services
{
internal class WindowLauncherService
{
    public static WindowLauncherService Instance { get; } = new WindowLauncherService();

    private Dictionary<int, WindowType> WindowLogs { get; set; }

    internal async void HandleWindowSwitch(WindowType typeOfWindow)
    {
        if (WindowLogs?.ContainsValue(typeOfWindow) == true)
        {

            var existingViewID = WindowLogs?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == typeOfWindow).Key;
            if (existingViewID != null)
            {
                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(Convert.ToInt32(existingViewID));
            }
            else
            {
                //Handle Error Here!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await OpenNewWindow(typeOfWindow);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the new window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WindowID">The window identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="typeOfWindow">The type of window.</param>
    private void LogNewWindow(int WindowID, WindowType typeOfWindow)
    {
        if (WindowLogs?.ContainsKey(WindowID) == true)
            return;

        if (WindowLogs == null)
            WindowLogs = new Dictionary<int, WindowType>();

        WindowLogs.Add(WindowID, typeOfWindow);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the new window and if success logs it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeOfWindow">The type of window.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task OpenNewWindow(WindowType typeOfWindow)
    {
        Type windowToLaunch = null;
        switch (typeOfWindow)
        {
            case WindowType.Main:
                windowToLaunch = typeof(MainPage);
                break;
            case WindowType.First:
                windowToLaunch = typeof(Scenarios.FirstWindow);
                break;
            case WindowType.Second:
                windowToLaunch = typeof(Scenarios.SecondWindow);
                break;
            case WindowType.Third:
                windowToLaunch = typeof(Scenarios.ThridWindow);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }



        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

        var currentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (currentFrame.Content is MainPage)
        {
            var mainFrameID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            LogNewWindow(mainFrameID, WindowType.Main);
        }

        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(windowToLaunch, null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
            Window.Current.Activate();

            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
        if (viewShown)
        {
            LogNewWindow(newViewId, typeOfWindow);
        }
        else
        {
            //handle error on launch here!
        }
    }

}

public enum WindowType
{
    Main,
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}
}
```

And on button click this is what you do:

```
private void HandleWindowChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as Button;
        var conversionSuccessful = Enum.TryParse((string)s.Tag, true, out Services.WindowType TypeOfWindow);
        if (conversionSuccessful)
        {
            Services.WindowLauncherService.Instance.HandleWindowSwitch(TypeOfWindow);
        }
    }
```

**Please Note:** All Buttons in all views have the same click event code and they all call the same singleton instance.

---

Refer to my source code from one drive. For any help do let me know in the comments section. **Please note** I am using VS2017, if you're using older versions, few things might not be available for eg: the `out` keyword in `Enum.TryParse<>`
[The Link to the complete solution on github](https://github.com/ImCarrot/MultipleWindowTrackerDemo-Stack)

Comment: Ah, so you are using an ApplicationViewSwitcher... hmmm. Let me try that tomorrow, I will let you know. Nice solution, BTW. THANKS

Comment: Yeah, it was the only way to switch. Unless there is another way which I am guessing is not there else, people would have answered the question. do let me know about the results. There is a sample solution uploaded on onedrive as well

Comment: @J.H.has the issue been resolved by this answer? if yes could you please mark my answer as correct (or even upvote it, if you liked the approach) so that this thread will be closed?

Comment: I am the worst of the worst. So sorry. Got totally sidelined from this issue. Should be able to go back to this one by the end of the month... ah the urgency of the NOW ;-)

Comment: so, finally got around to test this. Impressive work on the wrapper, but the result is still ... nothing. `TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` simply does not bring the child window to the front... I am sure the actual app is pull up, but since I interacted with it, it is in the front already... What I am looking for is a way to pop the child window...

Comment: @J.H. I've uploaded the source code to GitHub. It's working just fine could you please confirm if it's working on your system or does the issue still persist